# A question about local compactness and $\sigma$-compactness

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $X$ be locally compact metric space which is $\sigma$-compact also. I want to show that $X=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n$, where $K_n$'s are compact subsets of $X$ satisfying $K_n\subset K_{n+1}^{0}$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

I know that since $X$ is $\sigma-$compact, therefore there exists a sequence of compact subsets $(C_n)$ of $X$ such that $X=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n$. I am not getting any idea how to construct $K_n$'s. Please help!

Comment: Being able to find the $K_n$ is called that $X$ is so-called hemicompact. Note that a hemicompact Hausdorff space is locally compact. The proof @bof  gave shows that locally compact + $\sigma$-compact implies hemicompact. So the reverse also holds. $\mathbb{Q}$ is an example of a non-hemicompact $\sigma$-compact space.

Comment: Actually, hemicompact is a slightly weaker property (see wikipedia).  The desired property here is that $X$ be [exhaustible by compact sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhaustion_by_compact_sets). There are spaces that are hemicompact without being exhaustible by compact sets, for example the Arens-Fort space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $X$ is locally compact, every compact subset of $X$ is contained in an open set whose closure is compact.

Since $X$ is $\sigma$-compact, there are compact subsets $C_n$ such that $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C_n.$

Since $C_1$ is compact, there is an open set $U_1$ such that $\overline{U_1}$ is compact and $C_1\subseteq U_1.$

Since $\overline{U_1}\cup C_2$ is compact, there is an open set $U_2$ such that $\overline{U_2}$ is compact and $\overline{U_1}\cup C_2\subseteq U_2.$

Continue in this manner. Let $K_n=\overline{U_n}.$ Then $K_n$ is compact, $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty K_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \overline{U_n}\supseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty U_n\supseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C_n=X,$ and $K_n=\overline{U_n}\subseteq U_{n+1}\subseteq K_{n+1}^\circ.$

Answer (score 2):

The desired property is called the existence of an [exhaustion by compact sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhaustion_by_compact_sets) for the space $X$. (see Wikipedia)

The answer of @bof holds in the context of locally compact Hausdorff spaces (since the OP mentioned metric spaces).  But the result is more generally true for [weakly locally compact spaces](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000023), that is, [locally compact spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) in the weakest sense in that each point has a compact neighborhood.

> **Proposition:** The following are equivalent for a topological space $X$:
>
> 1. $X$ is exhaustible by compact sets.
> 2. $X$ is $\sigma$-compact and weakly locally compact.
> 3. $X$ is [Lindelöf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space) and weakly locally compact.

We need a preliminary

> **Lemma**: In a weakly locally compact space $X$, for every compact subset $K\subseteq X$ there is a compact subset of $X$ containing $K$ in its interior.

To see this, every point $x\in K$ has a compact nbhd.  Since $K$ is covered by the interiors of all these nbhds, it is covered by a finite number of these interiors, and the union of those finitely many compact nbhds is compact and contains $K$ in its interior.

Now the proof of the proposition.

(1) implies (2): Suppose $X=\bigcup_n K_n$ with each $K_n$ compact and $K_n\subseteq\operatorname{int}(K_{n+1})$.  Clearly $X$ is $\sigma$-compact.  Also the interiors of the $K_n$ cover $X$, so $X$ is weakly locally compact.

(2) implies (3): because $\sigma$-compact implies Lindelöf.

(3) implies (2): Since $X$ is weakly locally compact, every point is in the interior of some compact set.  By the Lindelöf property $X$ is covered by the interiors of a countable number of these compact sets, and hence by a countable number of these compact sets themselves.

(2) implies (1): This is just a modification of the argument from @bof.  Suppose $X=\bigcup_n C_n$ with each $C_n$ compact.  Take $K_1=C_1$.  The set $K_1\cup C_2$ is compact. So by the lemma it is contained in the interior of some compact set $K_2$.  Continuing like this, at each step choose $K_{n+1}$ compact such that $K_n\cup C_{n+1}\subseteq\operatorname{int}(K_{n+1})$. The result is an increasing sequence of compact sets, each contained in the interior of the next one, and adding up to the whole space, that is, an exhaustion of $X$ by compact sets.