# Do homeomophisms of subspaces preserve the subspaces topological structure in the parent space?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

To make this question more precise, suppose $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces and let $A \subseteq X$ and $B \subseteq Y$ be subspaces. Suppose $A$ is open in $X$ and $A$ is homomorphic to $B$, does it follow that $B$ is open in $Y$?

What if I replaced "open", with "closed" or "compact" or "connected", or "locally connected" etc.

Loosely speaking this amounts to *"Do homeomophisms of subspaces preserve the subspaces topological structure in the parent space?"*

Comment: Let $Y$ be a space and $B$ a subset of $Y$ which is neither open nor closed. Let $A=X=B.$ Then $A$ is homeomorphic to $B,$ and $A$ is open and closed in $X,$ but $B$ is neither open nor closed in $Y.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Homeomorphisms preserve topological properties, but relative properties need not be preserved.

Openness and closedness are relative properties, not topological properties.

For example . . .

Any open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is homemeomorphic to itself, regarded as a subspace of $\mathbb{R^2}$, but in $\mathbb{R^2}$, it's no longer open.

The graph of $e^x$ is closed in $\mathbb{R^2}$, and is homeomorphic to the subspace $(0,\infty)$ of $\mathbb{R}$, which is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

However compactness, connectedness, local connectedness are topological properties, so are preserved by homeomorphisms.

The bottom line: If you can define a property using the topology of the space itself, without regard to a parent space, then it's a topological property.

Answer (score 4):

For closed sets, the answer is negative: take $\mathbb Z$ and $\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ as subsets of $\mathbb R$.

For open sets, the answer is negative too: take the subsets $(0,1]$ and $(1,2]$ of $(0,2]$. They are homeomorphic, but $(1,2]$ is open, whereas $(1,2]$ isn't.

For connected and compact sets, the answer is affirmative: being compact or connected does not depend upon the environment.