# Existence of an increasing sequence of compact sets with a given property

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

Let $S$ be a bounded sigma-compact subset of a separable infinite dimensional Hilbert space. Can we always find an increasing sequence of compact sets $K_n$ such that $S=\cup_nK_n$ and for any compact subset K of S there exists a natural number $N$ such that K is contained in the union of the first N of the $K_n$?

Comment: A first-countable Hausdorff space with this property is [necessarily locally-compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2917378/a-first-countable-hemicompact-space-is-locally-compact). Thus it must fail for any infinite-dimensional Hilbert space (we can take $S$ to be the unit ball of a countably infinite-dimensional linear subspace, for instance).

Comment: Oh you are right! Thanks very much for your answer, it is all clear now.

Comment: The space itself doesn't have this property but any $\sigma$-compact sub-set will.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? I would be interested to see the proof.

Comment: Actually I was mistaken - the proof I had in mind used local compactness. The argument described by Tyrone is correct: A countably infinite dimensional subspace is $\sigma$-compact, if the statement is true the countable infinite dimensional subspace must then be hemi-compact and as such locally compact  / finite dimensional, a contradiction.