# Can a hemicompact space fail to be weakly locally compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

In [A first countable hemicompact space is locally compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2917378/a-first-countable-hemicompact-space-is-locally-compact) we can see a proof that every [first-countable](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000028) [hemicompact](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000111) space is [weakly locally compact](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000023).

If first-countability is dropped, is this still true? In other words, is there a hemicompact space that is not weakly locally compact?  pi-base currently [does not have an example of this](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=hemicompact%2B%7EWeakly%20Locally%20Compact).

Comment: As of now, several examples have been added to pi-base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\{x_n:n<\omega\}$ be a countable and [anticompact](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000136) (every compact subset is finite) space. Then $X$ is hemicompact ([T000291](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000291)): let $K_n=\{x_i:i<n\}$, then every compact is finite and thus contained in some $K_n$.

Then if such a space contains a point with no finite neighborhoods, such as the [Arens-Fort Space](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000023) or [Appert space](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000096), the space cannot be weakly locally compact.

Answer (score 0):

Going over the linked page 20 in "*Counterexamples in Topology*" by Lynn A. Steen and J. Arthur Seebach, I assume "weakly locally compact" is just "locally compact". There is an example of a hemicompact, but not locally compact space found in Chapter 4, Section 2, Example 10 and Exercise 8 in "*Introduction to General Topology*" (See [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=fvCpXrube5wC&printsec=copyright#v=onepage&q&f=false).) by K. D. Joshi.

Comment: That seems to be the same as the Arens-Fort space.

Comment: Indeed it is! I haven't known the space under this name and haven't clicked on the link in the answer of Steven Clontz before answering myself. Well, still useful to have a reference to literature.

Comment: Yeah, as indicated in Steven Clontz's link, it's counterexample #26 in Steen & Seebach.

Comment: *another reference