# Without Hausdorff, what implications can we prove about $k_\omega$ related to other covering properties?

Tags: general-topology

In e.g. [A SURVEY OF $k_\omega$-SPACES](http://topology.nipissingu.ca/tp/reprints/v02/tp02105.pdf) a space is said to be $k_\omega$ if it's the union of compact Hausdorff $K_n$, $n<\omega$, with a set being closed if and only if its intersection with each $K_n$ is closed.

It's asserted there that $k_\omega$ is implied by $K_n\subseteq int(K_{n+1})$, i.e. [exhaustible by (Hausdorff) compacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhaustion_by_compact_sets).

I want to consider the case where the $K_n$ need not be Hausdorff. In this case, we have exhaustible by compacts $\Rightarrow$ hemicompact $\Rightarrow$ $\sigma$-compact (with no arrows reversing). Where does this non-$T_2$ $k_\omega$ live?

---

Exhaustible by compacts implies this $k_\omega$. Let $K_n\subseteq int(K_{n+1})$. $k_\omega$ is equivalent to a set having open intersection with each $K_n$ with respect to the subspace topology implies the set is open. So let $U$ have open intersection with each $K_n$ and let $x\in U$. Note $x\in K_n$ for some $n<\omega$. Then let $V$ be an open set such that $V\cap K_{n+1}=U\cap K_{n+1}$. $x\in V\cap int(K_{n+1})\subseteq U$, proving $U$ is open.

Obviously, $k_\omega$ still implies $\sigma$-compact. Where does hemicompact fit in without something like Hausdorff or locally compact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this is a little old but I see the question is not resolved yet.  Here is the answer.

> **Definition.** $X$ is [**generated by compact sets** ($CG1$)](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000140) if for each subset $A\subseteq X$, $A$ is closed in $X$ if and only if $A\cap K$ is closed in $K$ for each compact $K$.

> **Proposition.** Let $X$ be a topological space.  Then $X$ is $k_\omega$ if and only if $X$ is $CG1$ and hemicompact.

**Proof.**

If $X$ is hemicompact and $CG1$, with hemicompactness witnessed by a sequence $\{K_n\}$, then suppose $A\subseteq X$, with $A\cap K_n$ closed in $K_n$ for each $n$.  Then for any compact $K$, choose $n$ with $K\subseteq K_n$.  Since $A\cap K_n$ is closed in $K_n$, $A\cap K= (A\cap K_n)\cap K$ is closed in $K$.  Thus by $CG1$, $A$ is closed in $X$, and so the sequence $K_n$ witnesses that $X$ is $k_\omega$.

Conversely, we first observe that the argument for 3) on page 113 of the [linked survey](http://topology.nipissingu.ca/tp/reprints/v02/tp02105.pdf) would work fine if we restricted ourselves to $T_1$ spaces.  For the general case, we modify it as follows.

Let $X$ be $k_\omega$, witnessed by $\{K_n\}$. For each $n$, let $L_n=\{x\in X\mid \overline{\{x\}}\cap K_n\neq \emptyset\}$.  We first observe that $L_n\supseteq K_n$, and $\mathcal U$ is an open cover of $K_n$ if and only if it is an open cover of $L_n$.  Indeed, if $\mathcal U$ covers $K_n$, and $x\in L_n$, then there is some $y\in\overline{\{x\}}\cap K_n$, and some $U\in \mathcal U$ with $y\in U$.  Then since $y\in \overline{\{x\}}$ and $U$ is a neighborhood of $y$, $U$ meets $\{x\}$, i.e., $x\in U$.  The other direction is trivial.

As a result, compactness of $K_n$ immediately implies compactness of $L_n$.  Note that $L_n$ is certainly an increasing sequence of compact sets.  Now suppose $K\subseteq X$ is compact.  We wish to show $K\subseteq L_n$ for some $n$, so supposing otherwise, choose $x_n\in K\backslash L_n$ for each $n$.  Then by definition, we have $\overline{\{x_n\}}\cap K_n=\emptyset$.

Now define $U_n=X\backslash\bigcup_{k\geq n} \overline{\{x_k\}}$.  Then for each $n$ and $m$, $U_n\cap K_m$ is open in $K_m$, since only finitely many of the closed sets $\overline{\{x_k\}}$ intersect $K_m$.  Since this holds for all $m$, by the $k_\omega$ condition, $U_n$ is open.  But then $\{U_n\}$ is an open cover of $K$ with no finite subcover, contradicting compactness.

Thus $X$ is hemicompact via the sequence $L_n$, and of course $k_\omega$ trivially implies $CG_1$.

---

**Remarks.**

Note that in contrast to the non-$T_1$ examples in PatrickR's answer, under $T_1$, the $k_\omega$ and hemicompact properties use the same sequence, since under $T_1$ we have $L_n=K_n$ in the above proof.

In general, we have the implications

$$\text{exhaustible-by-compacts}\implies k_\omega\implies \text{hemicompact}\implies \sigma\text{-compact},$$

all strict (even under separation as strong as $T_6$), with the converse of the first refuted by the [Arens space](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000156) (or any of the Fréchet-Urysohn counterexamples [discussed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4844346/1210477)), the converse of the second refuted by the Arens Fort space per PatrickR's answer, and the converse of the third refuted by many examples, including $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Very ingenious choice of $L_n$ in the proof.  I had to think a little about two details, which may be worth spelling out. (1) as $K_n\subseteq L_n$, the $k_\omega$ property is also witnessed by the  sequence of the $L_n$. (2) $\overline{\{x_n\}}\cap K_n=\emptyset$ also implies that $\overline{\{x_n\}}\cap L_n=\emptyset$.

Comment: @PatrickR while that's true, I think I goofed on this proof, and actually just meant to say $U_n\cap K_m$ is open in $K_m$, which makes none of that discussion necessary.  Going to fix that now [fixed now I think].

Comment: @PatrickR As for the choice of $L_n$, I was inspired by your non-$T_1$ counterexample of $\mathbb Z$ with the right order topology, looking at the difference between the original $k_\omega$ sequence and the final hemicompact one, it  became apparent that we were just including points whose closure met the original compact sets.  So thank you for that example, it was really the inspiration for this answer.

Comment: A trivial comment.  A *compactum* (plural *compacta*) usually means a compact set with some additional condition, metrizable in particular, or at least Hausdorff.  See for example Encyclopedia of General Topology (p. 122 and 169)

Answer (score 3):

*Edit: My original post contained a faulty counterexample with a rather obvious flaw. Since the rest of the post contained some useful (but well-known) material, I will leave this up as an extended comment.*

So you want to consider a space $X$ which is the colimit of an expanding sequence
$$X_1\subseteq X_2\subseteq\dots\subseteq X_n\subseteq\dots$$
of its compact (not necessarily Hausdorff) subspaces? Such an $X$ is Lindelöf, and is $T_1$ when each $X_n$ is $T_1$.

> In case $X$ is $T_1$, it is hemicompact.

*Proof:* Suppose that $K\subseteq X$ is a compact subset not contained in any $X_n$. We can assume without loss of generality that the $X_n$ are all distinct and that $K\cap X_1\neq\emptyset$. For each $n\geq0$ choose $x_n\in K\cap(X_n\setminus X_{n-1})$, where we understand $X_{0}=\emptyset$. Write $D=\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subseteq X$. If $C\subseteq D$ is any subset, then $C$ is closed in $D$, since for each $n$ we have that $C\cap X_n$ is finite and hence closed in $X_n$. It follows that $D$ is infinite, discrete and closed in $X$, and this contradicts the compactness of $K$. $\;\blacksquare$

On the other hand, with not separation assumptions we have;

> If $X_n$ is open in $X_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $X$ is hemicompact.

*Proof:* The family $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a an open cover of $X$. $\;\blacksquare$

**Example 0:** *A hemicompact example which is not exhaustible by compacts.*

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $X_n=\bigvee^n_{i=1}S^1$ and equip $X=\bigcup^\infty_{i=1}X_n$ with the colimit topology. As a countable CW complex, $X$ is a Hausdorff $k_\omega$-space. If $X$ had a sequence of exhaustion $K_1\subseteq int(K_2)\subseteq K_2\dots$, then each point of $X$ would be contained in the interior of one of the compact $K_n$'s. Since each compact subset of a CW complex is metrisable, each point of $X$ would therefore have a metrisable neighourhood. But a locally metrisable paracompact space is metrisable, and $X$ is not even first-countable at the wedge point. $\;\square$

Comment: Something not quite right about Example 1, as compact sets are always hemicompact. The indiscrete topology is both hemicompact and $k_\omega$, and exhaustible by compacts.  (take each $K_n$ to be the whole space)

Comment: @PatrickR you're right, thanks for pointing out the rather obvious mistake :(.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but some obervations.  Hereafter $k_\omega$ will mean the version without Hausdorff.

A hemicompact space need not be $k_\omega$, even in the Hausdorff case.  The survey article gives as an example on p. 114 a certain subspace of the Cech-Stone compactification $\beta\mathbb{N}$.

Another example is the Arens-Fort space.  As shows [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4566624) this space $X$ is hemicompact.  But it is not $k_\omega$.  Indeed, it is anticompact and $T_1$, so every compact subspace is finite with the discrete topology.  So every subset $A\subseteq X$ meets every compact subspace $K\subseteq X$ in a closed subset of $K$, but not every subset of $X$ is closed since the space is not discrete.  This shows that $X$ does not admit any $k_\omega$ decompsition $(X_n)$.

So the other question is: does $k_\omega$ imply hemicompact?

The tricky thing seems that given a $k_\omega$ decomposition $(X_n)$, it is not necessarily the case that the space will be hemicompact with respect to that decomposition, but it could still be hemicompact with respect to a different decomposition.

Example 1 from Tyrone (now edited out, but available in the edit history) illustrates this.  Taking $X=\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,...\}$ with the indiscrete topology, the sets $X_n=[1,n]$ (in the usual order on $X$) form a $k_\omega$ decomposition but not every compact subset ($X$ in particular) is contained in one of the $X_n$.  But $X$ is still hemicompact because it is compact.

Another example is $X=\mathbb{Z}$ with the right order topology.  Open sets are of the form $[n,\infty)$ and compact sets are the ones with a minimum element.  The sets $X_n=[-n,n]$ form a $k_\omega$ decomposition (easy to check the weak topology condition), but the compact set $[0,\infty)$ is not contained in any of the $X_n$.  Note that in this case the closure of any of the $X_n$ is not even compact.  But $X$ is still hemicompact by taking $X_n=[-n,\infty)$ for example.

---

(Added 12/11/2022): The paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04857 by T. Banakh uses the notions of $k_\omega$ and hemicompact spaces without assuming Hausdorff.

On the bottom of p. 8 it states:

> "Each $k_\omega$-space is hemicompact."

Also on p. 16 before Lemma 2.5.1 it restates the same thing:

> "It is known that each $k_\omega$-sequence $(K_n)_{n\in\omega}$ in a topological space X swallows compact subsets of the space
> in the sense that each compact subset $K\subset X$ is contained in some set $K_n$."

But this last sentence cannot be true in general without Hausdorff, as my two examples above show.  Could be worth asking the author about it.

Comment: "But this last sentence cannot be true in general without Hausdorff, as my two examples above show. Could be worth asking the author about it."  It turns out it is true under $T_1$ (see answer below).  Glancing at the paper it looks like the author is mostly interested in $T_1$ spaces, so I'd guess it's just an oversight.

Answer (score 2):

A partial result adapting [4.3 of this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1974-191-00/S0002-9947-1974-0352320-6/) assuming the space is first-countable and $T_1$. Let $K_n$ for $n<\omega$ witness some $k_\omega$ decomposition with $K_n\subseteq K_{n+1}$. Suppose, aiming for a contradiction, some $p\in X$ has no compact neighborhood; in particular, no $K_n$ is a compact neighborhood of $p$. Without loss of generality, assume $p\in K_0$. Then if $\{U_n:n<\omega\}$ is the guaranteed (by first-countability) countable base at $p$, $U_n\not\subseteq K_n$; pick $p_n\in U_n\setminus K_n$. Then $\{p_n:n<\omega\}$ is closed as it has finite (a subset of $\{p_m:m<n\}$, and therefore closed by $T_1$) intersection with each $K_n$. But $p\not\in\{p_n:n<\omega\}$ is a limit point as $p_n\in U_n$ for all $n<\omega$, a contradiction.

So every first-countable $T_1$ $k_\omega$ space is weakly locally compact. Since weakly locally compact and $\sigma$-compact spaces are hemicompact, and [first-countable hemicompact spaces are all weakly locally compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2917378/), $k_\omega$ and hemicompact are equivalent for first-countable $T_1$ spaces.