# A topological space $(X, \tau)$ which is: $\sigma-$ compact, Hausdorff, and locally compact. Then X is also paracompact.

Tags: general-topology, paracompactness

A topological space is called $\sigma$-compact if it is a countable union of compact sets.

Comment: Please give the definition of paracompactness and state the question explicitly. I presume that you are wanting a proof of the statement in the title?

Comment: @user558840: Paracompactness is a standard, basic topological property; there is no need to define it in the question.

Comment: locally compact is overkill: regular is enough. Without regularity there are plenty of counterexamples, see [$\pi$-base](https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces?q=%24%5Csigma%24-compact%20%2B%20%24T_2%24%20%2B~%20Paracompact) e.g.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott My question on paracompactness was partly for pedagogic reasons and partly to encourage a new contributor by showing an interest in the question. Also I seldom use paracompactness and I struggle to remember the definition (and may be typical of many users in this respect).

Comment: Please write the question in the question body itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: A $\sigma$-compact space is easily shown to be Lindelöf, and a locally compact Hausdorff space is regular. Finally, regular Lindelöf spaces are paracompact.