# A $\sigma$-compact but not hemicompact space?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

All spaces are at least Hausdorff. A topological space $X$ is called

- *$\sigma$-compact* if there is a countable sequence $(K_n)_{n<\omega}$ of compact subsets of $X$ such that $X=\bigcup_n K_n$.
- *hemicompact* if there is a countable sequence $(K_n)_{n<\omega}$ of compact subsets of $X$ such that for every $K\subseteq X$ compact there is $n\in\omega$ with $K\subseteq K_n$.

In particular a hemicompact space $X$ is $\sigma$-compact since for every $x\in X$ there is $n$ with $\{x\}\subseteq K_n$, hence $X=\bigcup_n K_n$. I'm interested in conditions on $X$ that are sufficient to reverse this implication, but I am more interested in an example of a space $X$ (with $X$ at least Hausdorff, better if completely regular) which is $\sigma$-compact but not hemicompact. I have checked the standard sources (Counterexamples in Topology and the pi-base website) but there are no examples of such spaces there, hence my question:

What is an example of an Hausdorff space $X$ which is $\sigma$-compact but not hemicompact?

Comment: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000027/properties/P000111

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very simple example is the rational numbers.  Obviously $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\sigma$-compact by covering it with singletons.  However, I claim it is not hemicompact.  Indeed, suppose $(K_n)$ is a sequence of compact subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$.  Each $K_n$ does not contain any neighborhood of $0$, so we can pick a sequence $(x_n)$ where each $x_n\not\in K_n$ and $x_n\to 0$.  Then the set $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}$ is compact but not contained in any $K_n$.

More generally, this argument shows that a hemicompact first-countable space must be locally compact (in the weak sense of having a compact neighborhood of every point).  So any $\sigma$-compact first-countable space that is not locally compact is a counterexample.