# Does locally compact and $\sigma$-compact non-Hausdorff space imply hemicompact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I know $\sigma$-compact locally compact Hausdorff spaces are hemicompact. What if we remove the Hausdorff condition or replace Hausdorff with $T_1$?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [A question about local compactness and $\sigma$-compactness](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2078142/721644) ?

Comment: @SummerChild I don't think so. Hausdorff is the assumption used there.

Comment: Maybe you should also include that in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can drop the Hausdorff condition completely. In analogy to the theorem, that locally compact and $\sigma$-compact spaces are paracompact (See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+compact+and+sigma-compact+spaces+are+paracompact)), we have:

**Theorem**: Locally compact and $\sigma$-compact spaces are hemicompact (Proof see [here](https://planetmath.org/hemicompactspace)).

There is an example of a hemicompact, but not locally compact space found in Example 10, Chapter 4, Section 2 in *Introduction to General Topology* by K. D. Joshi. Nonetheless, a first countable and hemicompact space is locally compact (Proof see [here](https://planetmath.org/hemicompactspace)). The inverse direction holds for the other condition though: Hemicompact spaces are $\sigma$-compact (See [here](https://planetmath.org/hemicompactspace)). On the other hand, $\mathbb{Q}$ is a $\sigma$-compact, but not hemicompact space (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4209303/a-sigma-compact-but-not-hemicompact-space)).

Comment: Your answer saves my day! Thanks a lot. I once thought Hausdorff is needed. I concluded that LCH and sigma-compact imply hemicompact from Folland's Real Analysis Proposition 4.39 and 4.40's proof. Now I know, it actually does not need Hausdorff.

Answer (score 3):

As you probably know, without the Hausdorff property there are various inequivalent notions of [locally compact space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space).  The weakest of them being [weakly locally compact](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000023), that is every point has a compact nbhd (= [condition (1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_locally_compact) in Wikipedia).

Now the planetmath proof of the result mentioned in @SamuelAdrianAntz's answer seems to make some assumptions (open sets with compact closure, ...) which do not always hold.  But the following more general result is true.

> **Theorem:** Every weakly locally compact $\sigma$-compact space is hemicompact.

Proof: As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4568032/52912), being weakly locally compact and $\sigma$-compact is equivalent to being [exhaustible by compact sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhaustion_by_compact_sets).  So we can find a sequence of compact sets $K_n$ in the space $X$, each contained in the interior of the next one, and whose union is the whole set.  Note that the interiors of all the $K_n$ also cover the whole space.  Now given any compact set $K\subseteq X$, it is contained in the union of the interiors of the $K_n$.  Thus, by compactness it is contained in the interior of one of the $K_n$, and also in $K_n$.  In other words, $X$ is hemicompact.